# using match(), but it didn't work froma string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following fiddle:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6w4k/1/)

The function:

```
$('#testbutton').on("click", function(){
    test();
});

function test()
{
    var data = [];
    data['article'] = "monablanko";
    data['specialarticle'] = ["blanko", "bbsooel"];

    var tmp = data['specialarticle'].join("|");
    if( data['article'].match( /(tmp)/ ) )
    {
        $('#result').html("I found a match");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#result').html("I didn't found a match");
    }
}
```

I didn't found a match with this function. Where is my error? The typeof tmp is string when i use

console.log(typeof tmp);

when i write

```
if( data['article'].match( /(blanko|bbsooel)/ ) )
```

then i find a match.

Comment: Just wondering, but why are you using string indices in an array?  (Yes, it technically works, but it's not what they're designed for).

Comment: String indices can make code easier to read because you can give the array values a name that you can remember and can be meaningful. it makes the code slightly harder to maintain (because a string is easier to make a mistake in than a number) though. A better option would be to create an object, though. You can still use a meaningful name, but you get intellisense in most sensible IDEs that can make names harder to mess up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching against the string literal `"tmp"`, not against the value contained inside the variable `tmp`. Try it like this:

```
 data['article'].match( new RegExp("(" + tmp + ")") )
```

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/4K8Km/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a RegExp to match your string before:

```
$('#testbutton').on("click", function(){
  test();
});

function test(){
  var data = [];
  data['article'] = "monablanko";
  data['specialarticle'] = ["blanko", "bbsooel"];

  var tmp = new RegExp('('+data['specialarticle'].join("|")+')');
  if( data['article'].match( tmp ) )
  {
    $('#result').html("I found a match");
  }
  else
  {
    $('#result').html("I didn't found a match");
  }
}
```

Just one more tip: if you don't need to collect a match, but just to test if the string has that RegExp I would suggest to use `test` instead of `match`:

```
tmp.test(data['article']);
```

rather than

```
data['article'].match(tmp);
```

Comment: it always goes to if condition even string doesn't match

Comment: If it doesn't match it should return `null` which is falsy.